# How can I get which cell within the two-dimensional array my sprite is in?

Tags: java, sprite, multidimensional-array

I am working on this game and everything is running alright. I am still fairly new to Java and specially with 2D Java. There are still some things I want to do but I really don't know how.

What I want to do is create a method or something to be able to get which cell my player is located at within the two-dimensional array I have as my map. I have used other sources from tutorials and then I have added some thing that I made as well.

[Map] (http://pastebin.com/H6FiSqj1)
[Player] (http://pastebin.com/ALMeBX3A>)

ADDITIONAL: I want to load the tiles from a seperate file. I have a MapLoader class but it is only letting me post 2 links.

Comment: Can think of two things. 1- Store the cell value as a separate variable.  This will make retrieval much faster. 2- Read the array in a nested `for-loop` looking for the player marker in the array...

Comment: playerx/width, playery/height, for the width and heights of the tiles, this is integer division.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the next [library](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) to design your game, where you can find very useful tools like one to design tile maps: [TileMaps](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps)

In order to know the position of your character into the map, I would save its position with coordinates (X and Y - 2D or X, Y and Z - 3D), so you know in every moment where exactly he is. With this pattern, every time that your character moves, you will increase/decrease in 1 movement unit your coordinates.